# Count how many times a word is found in a file

Tags: c#

I want to count how many times a word appears in a file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Should this have a "homework" tag?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? (1) reading a file, (2) splitting the file into words, (3) counting the occurrences of a word, (4) printing the result?

Comment: but you already know the easy way -- to ask on stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: You probably could have saved some typing if you would have just copied the text into Word.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a straight-forward text file, it is profoundly simple in c#...

```
private static int GetWordCount(string fileName, string word)
{
     string content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
     string[] words = content.Split(new char[] {'.', '.', ' ', '?', '\n', '\r'},
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     return words.Count(q => q == word);
}
```

This method reads the text into a string and then splits the string according to some delimiters.  Then a LINQ function is invoked to obtain and reurn the count.

Comment: I want to count every words count in a file. Would you provide me a solution?

Comment: That's easy enough to do, but it's actually a different question.  This question has to do with counting the occurrences of a single word.  A new question should be opened for a different question, and I now see the higher ups have closed this question...

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     StreamReader oReader;
     if (File.Exists(@"C:\TextFile.txt"))
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search");
          string cSearforSomething = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
          oReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\TextFile.txt");
          string cColl = oReader.ReadToEnd();
          string cCriteria = @"\b"+cSearforSomething+@"\b";
          System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex oRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(cCriteria,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

          int count = oRegex.Matches(cColl).Count;
          Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

OR

Another method. This may help you better understand.

Using Collections / Generics concept we will achieve our criteria easily . Please check the below code and update as per your scenerio.

1.) Initially read the text file (using `filestream` and imports `IO` namespace) ,

```
System.IO.StreamReader StreamReader1 =
new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("test.txt"));
```

2.) Append into the string builder.

```
StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();
sbData.Append(StreamReader1.ReadToEnd());
```

3.) Split the words from the `StringBuilder` (Spaces, Fullstops, Question Marks, Exclamations, Apostrophes, New Lines)

```
string[] arrDataCollection = sbData.ToString().Split(' ');
```

4.) Create dictionary for `SortedList`.

```
SortedList<int, string> slData = new SortedList<int, string>();
```

5.) Loop the Spilt Data and get the distinct collections.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Words.Length; i++)
{
    slData.Add(i, arrDataCollection[i]);
}
```

6.) Get the distinct words, count and please save into one `Hashtable`.

```
Hashtable htCollections = new Hashtable();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in slData )
{
    table.Add(kvp.Value, kvp.Key );
}
```

7.) Finally filter it from `Hashtable` as per our requirements, Hope this will help you.

Comment: But I still don't know how to use the created hashtable?

Comment: May be i don't describe my problems exactly. For example: string []str=new string[]{"words","values","words","values","Test","words"};I want to get the count of "words","values" and "Test".